# <Android> Status bar notification does not get updated

Tags: android, notifications

I am sending a status bar notification in my application. Always appearing the 1st notification ,when i send my second(subsequent) notification it does not get updated and always show the first one. I am a new bee to Android , please help me to isolate the issue.

My code goes as below

```
//create notification manager
NotificationManager mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
//create notifcation
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"My App", System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),SaveTask.class);
 notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "New Msg","First message", pendingNotificationIntent);

mManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should start using Notification.Builder rather than directly create a new instance of Notification class

Here is what it should look using NotificationBuilder:

```
//create notification manager
        NotificationManager mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MyActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTicker("My App")
                .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
                .setContentTitle("New Msg")
                .setContentText("First message")
                .build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mManager.notify(98038, notification);
```